# Inserting raw object data to django database

Tags: django, database

I am currently making django website with some static content for the site.
At first I use some kind of text file for static settings but I decided to change it into a database object.
Is there a way to insert raw data or even a class into a database so I can create a model that can have varying field type between rows.

For now I use:

```
class SiteStatic(models.Model):
    static_title = models.CharField()
    static_content = models.TextField()
```

The idea is to have a table that contain all static type for the website.
Something like

Site title: String

Video Splash: Url

Show Comment: Boolean

Etc...

What is the best way to achieve this effect?

Comment: Please indicate whether you are looking for a structured model for which a database approach is applicable. I.e. your columns or well-defined. Or whether you require an unstructured approach; in that case JSON or XML might be more applicable rather than the relational DB approach.

Comment: Well, unstructured approach seems like the answer but I also want to present it in the administration. Isn't it easier to have a database model in djago for this case?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the admin, the relational database approach is the one you have to take.